# Modsecurity blocks blocks my legit XHR POST request (403 forbidden)

Tags: nginx, waf, mod-security

I'm new to modsecurity topic so maybe my question is stupid but...

I have setup modsecurity on my new nginx/1.24.0 server with default set of recommended rules: coreruleset-3.3.0 and since then my POST XHR request is being blocked.
This is a basic Laravel/Livewire form.

The headers sent and logged by modsecurity look like:

```
POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0
content-type: application/json
origin: https://example.com
referer: https://example.com/en
pragma: no-cache
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkJVTXpEK01rYTRYVFI1aGxjOE9T...
content-length: 540
accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
te: trailers
accept: */*
cache-control: no-cache
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-dest: empty
authorization: Basic Y2Z0cmFbjpjmdG9u
host: example.com
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
```

and the logs report:

1. "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric" - but I for me "540" looks numeric!

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^\d+$' against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-length' (Value: `540' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] 
[line "127"] 
[id "920160"] 
[msg "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric"] 
[data "540"] 
[severity "2"]
```

2. "Illegal Content-Type header" - how come "application/json" is illegal?

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^[\w/.+-]+(?... against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-type' (Value: `application/json' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] 
[line "915"] 
[id "920470"] 
[rev ""] 
[msg "Illegal Content-Type header"] 
[data "application/json"] 
[severity "2"]
```

3. "Invalid HTTP Request Line" - what is invalid about this: "POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0"?

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^(?i:(?:[a-... against variable `REQUEST_LINE' (Value: `POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] 
[line "47"] 
[id "920100"] 
[msg "Invalid HTTP Request Line"] 
[data "POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0"]
```

..and then the request is blocked

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `13' ) 
[file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] 
[line "80"] 
[id "949110"] 
[msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 13)"] 
[data ""] 
[severity "2"]
```

So I'm totally surprised and I don't know what can I do about this since the rules seem legit but also I don't feel like breaking any of them.

**EDIT** (responding to @franbuehler comment):

Testing with curl:

```
curl -v -d '{"arg":"foo", "arg2":bar}' -H "content-length: 25" -H "content-type: application/json" -H "x-format-output: txt-matched-rules" "https://example.com/livewire/update"
```

I'm also being 403 blocked:

```
---EdzD52pk---A--
[22/Jan/2024:12:50:45 +0000] 1705927845 127.0.0.1 57452 127.0.0.1 443
---EdzD52pk---B--
POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0
host: example.com
user-agent: curl/7.81.0
accept: */*
x-format-output: txt-matched-rules
content-length: 25
content-type: application/json


---EdzD52pk---F--
HTTP/2.0 403
Server: nginx/1.24.0
Date: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 12:50:45 GMT
Content-Length: 153
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close

---EdzD52pk---H--
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^\d+$' against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-length' (Value: `25' ) [file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "127"] [id "920160"] [rev ""] [msg "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric"] [data "25"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [hostname "127.0.0.1"] [uri "/livewire/update"] [unique_id "1705927845"] [ref "v114,2"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^[\w/.+-]+(?:\s?;\s?(?:action|boundary|charset|type|start(?:-info)?)\s?=\s?['\"\w.()+,/:=?<>@-]+)*$' against variable `REQUEST_HEADERS:content-type' (Value: `application/json' ) [file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "915"] [id "920470"] [rev ""] [msg "Illegal Content-Type header"] [data "application/json"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/255/153"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname "127.0.0.1"] [uri "/livewire/update"] [unique_id "1705927845"] [ref "v131,16t:lowercase"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `^(?i:(?:[a-z]{3,10}\s+(?:\w{3,7}?://[\w\-\./]*(?::\d+)?)?/[^?#]*(?:\?[^#\s]*)?(?:#[\S]*)?|connect (?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\.?(?::\d+)?|options \*)\s+[\w\./]+|get /[^?#]*(?:\?[^#\s]*)?(?:#[\S]*)?)$' against variable `REQUEST_LINE' (Value: `POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0' ) [file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "47"] [id "920100"] [rev ""] [msg "Invalid HTTP Request Line"] [data "POST /livewire/update HTTP/2.0"] [severity "4"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [hostname "127.0.0.1"] [uri "/livewire/update"] [unique_id "1705927845"] [ref "v0,30"]
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `13' ) [file "/etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "80"] [id "949110"] [rev ""] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 13)"] [data ""] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "127.0.0.1"] [uri "/livewire/update"] [unique_id "1705927845"] [ref ""]
```

Comment: CRS dev-on-duty here. Sorry for your inconvenience. To be honest, I don't know why these 3 rules (920160, 920100, 920100) are triggered. They shouldn't! 
I tried it with this example here against our (CRS) sandbox and I'm not able to reproduce the block: curl -v -d '{"arg":"foo", "arg2":bar}' -H "content-length: 37"  -H "content-type: application/json" -H "x-format-output: txt-matched-rules" "http://sandbox.coreruleset.org/livewire/update".
The only difference I see is http/2. Do you have the same block with http/1.1? Are you able to reproduce this behaviour with a curl request (1.1 and 2)?

Comment: Thanks @franbuehler for the suggestion - doing it from curl I'm being blocked the same way (http 1.1 and 2 act the same). I have updated my question to include the test you suggested.

Comment: Your installation seems to be very broken. You're probably using a broken nginx build. We already encountered similar problems, see this issue here for example, especially this comment: https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/issues/3117#issuecomment-1419548808 (they was using ppa:ondrej/nginx-stable).
Could you please try with the digitalwave packages linked in this comment above?

Answer (score -1):

CRS Dev on Duty here. I've already responded in a comment, but an answer might be easier to find. And it's worth answering, because such errors seem to occur from time to time.
It seems that there are incorrect tutorials or images out there (e.g. ppa:ondrej/nginx-stable) that lead to this broken behavior (blocking legitimate requests). For example, see this comment here (or issue) reporting a similar issue: https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/issues/3117#issuecomment-1419548808
The solution is to use a correct image or installation of packages.
If it helps, the Digitalwave company releases current packages of Nginx and ModSecurity. These are actively maintained and used by one of the CRS developers: https://modsecurity.digitalwave.hu/